# Spring 3 MVC Validation with Hibernate; error: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am just learning Spring3 Validation with Hibernate. I have this class but I am setting getting the following error

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.stutteringjohnsmith.model.Friend

I am doing the sample from

http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/web/spring-3-mvc-and-hibernate3-example-part1.html

but I change the Article to Friend! Please help me out

Comment: after doing some debug  I see I get the error in   sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(friend); which is all the way in the DAO..  Can someone please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for google's sake I wanted to give a suggestion: check your persistence.xml file to make sure there's a mapping for the class in question. In this case, there should be an entry as follows:

```
<persistence ...>
   <persistence-unit name="..." ...>
      <provider>...</provider>
      <class>com.sutteringjohnsmith.model.Friend</class>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Hope that helps someone...